# Swiftui - start & stop sceneView animation at specific frames

Tags: swift, swiftui, scenekit

How can I start/stop a sceneview animation at a specific frame? Right now the entire animation is showing and is playing which works good, but is there a way to only show a portion of the animation? (I can see that the `.scn` animation has a duration of 280.)

```
SceneView(
  scene: coordinator.animScene,
  delegate: coordinator
)

class SceneCoordinator: NSObject, SCNSceneRendererDelegate, ObservableObject {

 lazy var animScene: SCNScene = {
     let scene = SCNScene(named: "scene.scn")!
     return scene
  }()
}
```

Comment: Stack [48120932] - is this what you mean?

Comment: @Voltan is that meant to be a link?

Comment: Sorry, type that number into the  stack overflow search bar.  I thought it might help you.